# How can I change the resolution of passphrase splash screen?

Tags: display, display-resolution, plymouth, passphrase

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Desktop PC. But there were some issues with resolutions. My screen gets distorted if there is a wrong resolution. I managed to correct my login screen and desktop resolution to the optimum one i.e. 1440x900 at 75Hz. But the resolution where Ubuntu asks for decryption passphrase is still distorted. Is there any way to change its resolution?

What the real screen should look like:

[image]

[image: my screen]